# how to design mapping on an entity with multiple types of owners

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I had a design dilemma , suffering from my lack of experience

I have a table called Server . In one column , I need to hold a Foreign Key as the "owner" of this Server. But , the owner can be either a Vendor , or a Customer. So there are 3 possibilities :

1) Put a column for each type of owner

```
Server_Id | Server_Address | Vendor_Id | Customer_Id
```

2) Create a table for each type of owner

```
VendorServer_Id | Server_Address

CustomerServer_Id | Server_Address
```

the problem is , as you see , the number of tables or columns are increasing alongside the number of owner types . What is the conventional solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the cons of your approaches 
`Sol 1.` If this is the case, if a new owner type comes into picture tomorrow, need to create a new column to maintain its id. Also in all the rows, it could be either vendor_id or customer_id which wont look normalized. 
`Sol 2.` Need to create a new table for new owner type introduced in future. This is really expensive but better than `Sol 1`. 
I suggest you maintain two tables as follows

`Server_Detail` :

```
Server_Id | Server_Address | Owner_Id
```

`Owner_Detail` :

```
Owner_Id | Owner_Id_Type
```

`Owner_Id` in `Server_Detail` is in `foreign key` with `Owner_Id` in `Owner_Detail` table.

You could define `Owner_Type` as `enum` in your code which is today `Vendor` and `Customer`. The value in `Owner_Id` need to be interpreted based on `Owner_Type` value. 
Also its wise to create a table for `Owner_Type` as below

```
Owner_Id_Type | Description
```

and introduce a `foreign key` with `Server` table. This ensures that only a restricted `Owner_Type` is allowed.

Comment: but if i use this solution , then Owner_Id wont be a ForeignKey right ?

Comment: thanks for update , but this does not put a constraint on writing a non-existent value on Owner_Id still

Comment: I got it. updating the answer again now.

Comment: will this suits your requirement? Adding new Owner will be just adding an entry in Owner_Type table and adding entries in Owner_Detail table with this new Owner_Type.

Comment: I will use the owner_type owner_Id pair but i would not introduce an owner entity to my model at this stage , so i think it solves my main concern of having many more owner types. :)